# Using Sellix.io API to request product info with discord.js?

Tags: api, discord, discord.js, command, bots

I'm trying to create a line of commands using the sellix.io API ( [docs](https://developers.sellix.io/#introduction) ). Below is the command and what I have so far, it works... but only if I fetch the status which is in the first bracket [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yUb4.png). I cannot seem to fetch anything within the data/product/ example: title. I was wondering how I can get the API to go into there, and for example, fetch the title to return? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

module.exports = {
    name: 'product',
    description: 'gets product data',
        async execute(message, args) {
            const ID = args.slice(1).join(' ');

                const response = await fetch(
                    `https://dev.sellix.io/v1/products/${ID}`,
                    { headers: { Authorization: `Bearer smsuAVRQFJXhHKxOk6jI5hqUWtNgZ1BFeL6znoEiX1AvuVVGCdnckW7qGmXI8XwI`} }
                );

                const data = await response.json();

                let itemname = data.title;

                const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle(`**${itemname} Info:**`)
                .setDescription(`**Name:** ${itemname}`)
                .setColor('01a852')
                .setTimestamp(new Date().getTime())

    message.channel.send(embed);
  }}
```

The way the command works (or should work): `- product {product ID}` which will return info on the product. I can get it to work by changing `data.title` to `data.status` and it returns the status code, but mentioned about, I  cant fetch anything else (the useful stuff).

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** change `data.title` to `data.data.product.title`